# String or binary data would be truncated yet values are short enough to fit

Tags: .net, mysql, sql

As the title, I keep get the same error message when inserting new values yet my values were short enough to fit in the particular column which is annoying me now.

```
insert into x_licenseXservice(license_ID,service_ID)
VALUES('PSV(D)',2)
```

For column 'license_ID', data type was set to varchar(40)
For column 'service_ID', data type was set to smallint

Hopefully anyone may point out the problem, thanks~

Comment: check the table definition again.

Comment: problem solved, I do have another tracking table which auto created after i did the provision step. Once i changed the data type in the tracking table to larger type then is fine.